# HOG person detection and setting up one class SVM classifiers

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using HOG descriptors and SVM like the examples provided in OpenCV cpp samples to detect people. Following the sample, if I use:

```
hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
```

I obtain a processing rate of approximately 150ms per image, which is a good performance. The drawback is that I obtain also many false positives. I have used MIT person database (128*64 pixel images containing a person), to train a ONE CLASS SVM classifier, as I only have positive examples. I have obtained the HOG feature vector of the images (3780 values) for the 924 images in the database. I have trained the SVM as follows:

```
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type = CvSVM::ONE_CLASS;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
params.nu=0.5;
params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 1000, 1e-6);

CvSVM SVM;
Mat ClassOutput = Mat::ones(1,numImagesDB,CV_32F);
SVM.train_auto(trainingSVMData,ClassOutput,Mat(),Mat(),params);
int x=SVM.get_support_vector_count();
const float *v = SVM.get_support_vector(0);
vector<float> descriptorVector;

for(unsigned int i=0;i<trainingSVMData.cols;i++)
    descriptorVector.push_back(v[i]);
```

Obtaining one support vector of 3780 components. Inserting this SVM to he HOG descriptor:

```
hog.setSVMDetector(descriptorVector);
```

Problems I have:

- The processing now is extremely slow, almost 10 SECONDS for each frame !!!
- The alforithm is more robust, but the rectangle detecting the person is twice the size of the person in height and width.

Could anyone help me or give some advise about it? Why so slow?

Thank you all very much in advance,

Comment: i hope, you're doing this only *once*, not *per frame*

Comment: berak is correct, you don't need to apply the SVM every frame just once to the HOG classifier then use that as normal

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I do, this is the initializing process. In runtime I use Hog.detectMultiScale(). This is the method that takes almos 10 sec, when before took 150ms. Are the descriptorVectors to long for computation?

Comment: It is possible to know the size of vectors used by HOG.detectMultiScale?. My vectors contain 3780 components. Are they a lot? Maybe the use of PCA for dimensionality reduction could help?

Comment: This website might help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/